# how can a python shell different out put than python idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question regarding python I wrote a code in python shell that shows different output and python IDLE shows different output for the same piece of code

I try to write the same code twice on python shell then tried in IDLE.
Python v3.7

```
a="aster\n"
b="aster\n"
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

I expected the output should be the same for both the print statement

Comment: Please show us what you got in each console. You may need to explain the differences, if they are not obvious. One difference may be the space between lines--some consoles using no blank space between lines, some use one blank space. If the difference is the particular numbers, be aware that the `id` for a variable may change between runs of the program, even in the same environment. The different consoles are basically irrelevant for that issue.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I'm quite sure OP is referring to the fact that in one output the 2 lines print the same id and in another output they don't, due to string interning

Comment: @DeepSpace: If the questioner made that clear, it would be a good question. Mainly, why are strings interned for one console and not another, even when the versions of Python are (apparently) identical? But the questioner needs to explain if that is his issue and that is his question.

Answer (score 4):

It's an implementation detail.

In the interactive interpreter used by IDLE, each line is parsed and compiled separately, and it isn't bothering to check for `b` if a `str` object equal to `'aster\n'` is already allocated, so you get two distinct objects.

If you put this in a script, the entire script is parsed before the compiler uses the resulting AST to generate code. By parsing everything at once, the compiler can notice that the same immutable string is used in more than once place, which allows it to generate code that uses multiple references to the same underlying `str` object.

In general, you should only care about the output of `id` or the result of an `is` comparison if you assigned the value from one name to another your self; don't assume that two literals that look the same will share a single underlying object.

Answer (score -1):

> Help on built-in function id in module builtins:
>
> id(obj, /)
>      Return the identity of an object.
>
> This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
>      (CPython uses the object's memory address.)

As you can see `id` returns the memory address of the object. So even you run the same script you will get different addresses.

Comment: I'm quite sure OP is referring to the fact that in one output the 2 lines print the same id and in another output they don't, due to string interning

Comment: but why should I get different output for the same piece  of code on python shell and IDLE